# Change the linespacing locally in a package file

Tags: memoir, line-spacing

I am making a titlepage for my PhD thesis, in the `memoir` class, and I want to increase the line spacing slightly in the title.

How can I increase the line spacing? I have tried the `linespread{1.5}` command, but it has no effect.

Package file contents (filename UiTThesis.sty):

```
%%%% file UiTThesis.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{UiTThesis}[2020/06/19 v0.1 UiT PhD Thesis]

% Check that the memoir class is loaded
\@ifclassloaded{memoir}{\let\endUiTThesis\relax}{\let\endUiTThesis\endinput
    \PackageError{UiTThesis}{The UiTThesis package only works with the memoir class}%
    {\@ehd}}

% Load packages
\RequirePackage{lipsum}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}
\RequirePackage{microtype}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,
                linkcolor=blue,
                citecolor=red,
                linktoc=page]{hyperref}
                
\RequirePackage[backend=biber,
                maxcitenames=99,
                mincitenames=1,
                style=numeric-comp,
                maxbibnames=99,
                firstinits=false,
                hyperref=true,
                uniquelist=false,
                uniquename=false]
                {biblatex}
                
                % Make group of references that will not
                % appear in the references section
                % (citing papers in List of Papers)
                \DeclareBibliographyCategory{dontbib}

% Page layout
\setstocksize{240mm}{170mm}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\setlrmarginsandblock{2cm}{3cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout


% Define a title page
\newcommand*\uittitlepage{
    \begin{center}
    \begingroup
    \vspace{0.1\textheight}
    %\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\\[\baselineskip]
    {\huge\bfseries\@title} \\[\baselineskip]
    {\large\itshape Subtitle}
    %\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\\[\baselineskip]
    \vfill
    {\Large\bfseries\scshape\@author}\\[\baselineskip]
    \vfill
    {\large\itshape Submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements \\[0.5\baselineskip] for the degree of Philosophiae Doctor}\\[\baselineskip]
    \vfill
    {\large\bfseries Main Supervisor} \\ Firstname Lastname \\[\baselineskip]
    {\large\bfseries Co--Supervisor} \\ Firstname Lastname
    \vfill
    \large\@date
    \endgroup
    \end{center}
}

\endinput
```

MWE file

```
\documentclass[11pt,
               twoside,
               onecolumn,
               openright,
               final]
               {memoir}
               
\usepackage{UiTThesis}

\author{Firstname Lastname}
\title{A Very Scientific Title}

\begin{document}        
    \begin{titlingpage}
        \uittitlepage
    \end{titlingpage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As always on the size post full minimal examples not sniplets. I would never dsign a title page this way. I always do it in a separate file using the `titlingpage` environment.

Comment: Your actual problem comes from this: `{\huge\bfseries My large and long title with too small line spacing}`, as this means that the line spacing from after `}` is used.

Comment: I will post a mwe soon. This definition goes into a custom package document that I import, and I place the titlepage cmd in a titlingpage environment.

Comment: To me writing it like this make its overly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You are much better off doing this. Since there are now concluded paragraphs the line spacings of `\huge` etc works as expected. `{\Huge long text} end` will have the line spacing of the size `end` is typeset in.

Add `\bigskip`, `\vspace{...}` as needed

```
\begin{titlingpage}
\centering

\huge\bfseries My large and long title with too small line spacing

\large\itshape Subtitle

\Large\bfseries\scshape Author % write by hand
\vfill

\large\itshape Submitted in partial fulfillment of the requirements
for the degree of Philosophiae Doctor


\large\bfseries Main Supervisor
Firstname Lastname

\large\bfseries Co--Supervisor Firstname Lastname


\large date % write by hand
\end{titlingpage}
```